# Open Revision Graph using command line

Tags: tortoisesvn, revision, revision-graph

Is there a way to open (visual) revision graph of a project only using command line?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

The command would look like `TortoiseProc.exe /command:revisiongraph /path:<path-to-checkout>`

You should consult [automating TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) for an understanding of the TortoiseSVN CLI.

Comment: This is probably a different question but I wrote multiple commands -as you answered- in a batch file but just the first one is fired. weird

Comment: putting "start" for each line has solved the problem by the way.

Comment: That would happen because TortoiseProc only exits when the window is closed. `start` allows execution to proceed in your script.